# NextJS - How to pass select box value to the API call using getInitialProps

Tags: api, async-await, next.js

I want to send the selected value (Month) to the API from the DropdownButton as a post request.
I am fairly new to the NextJS and I will really appreciate it if someone can help me pass the drop-down selected value

Please see the code below.

**Code:**

```
class Reports extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        const res = await fetch("https:testendpoint",{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'ApiKey testapikey'
                },
            body: JSON.stringify({"from":"2022-{Month}-07T20:00:00.000Z","to":"2022-{Month}-07T21:00:00.000Z"})
        })
        const json = await res.json()
        return { 
          data: json.data.value
        } 
      }
    render() { 
        return (
            <DropdownButton>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="01">January</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">February</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="3">March</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>
        )
    }
}
```

In the above API call, I am sending date (from) and (to) and I want the selected month to override the post-request.

Answer (score 1):

You can do send selected months by this way :

```js
    
    const Reports = () => {
      const [selectedMonth, setSelectedMonth] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        async function postSelectedMonth() {
          let fromSelectedMonth = `2022-${selectedMonth}-07T20:00:00.000Z`;
          let toSelectedMonth = `2022-${selectedMonth}-07T21:00:00.000Z`;
    
          let response = await fetch("https:testendpoint", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Accept: "application/json",
              Authorization: "ApiKey testapikey",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              from: fromSelectedMonth,
              to: toSelectedMonth,
            }),
          });
          response = await response.json();
          dataSet(response);
        }
        
        selectedMonth && postSelectedMonth();
    
      }, [selectedMonth]);
    
      const monthChangeHandler = (e) => {
        let month = e.target.value;
        setSelectedMonth(month)
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <select name="months" id="month" onChange={(e) => monthChangeHandler(e)}>
            <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
            <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
            <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
            <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Reports;
```

Comment: Thank you Saurabh for the quick response quick question as I am fairly new to the reatJs and in my example, I am using getInitialProps but you are using useEffect() in your example. I want to display the API response data to my HTML and I am using this.props.response.data. If i use useEffect() how would i display the response data to my HTML?

Comment: Hi, If i understand the problem correctly. you can use both methods for fetching data. I used useEffect for calling an post req api with selected dropdown value. if you're comfortable with getInitialProps, use it for fetching data for your dropdown value. Otherwise, here's the nextjs example you can get help with https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side

Comment: The reason I am using getInitialPropd is that I want to make a server-side api call. However, useEffect is a client-side

Comment: Then you should use getInitialProps for your server-side GET request and useEffect for dynamic post request call.

Comment: but with the useEffect, won't i get the cross-side scripting issues by making a call to the server-side?